# How to separate css result from "editor windows" and "preview frame" of an website editor?

Tags: css, web-applications, editor, aem

I'm making a webapp editor where people can make pages.
The prolem is that if someone edit the css of the page (example: the input style) this changies have effects on the input fields of the editor also! It's normal maybe because are the same documents.

But I'm asking about its: Is it possible to "separate" the css files from the area of the result doc and the area of the editor?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to keep the two styles in the same file? If you ever have to rewrite your own styling, chances are that the changes made by the users will be lost?

You could apply a certain class to the elements that are edible by the user and in that way split things up. for example:

```
<form class="edit"></form> --> this will be changed 
<form></form>
```

Then in your css file:

```
 form.edit{
    color:green;
 }
```

Although the best thing to do is : Split the css! You'll thank me later :)

Edit: I don't have any experience myself with CQ5 but it seems that you can split the css. More info on this here: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/components/clientlibs.html

Comment: +1 split the css.  Possibly into separate clientlibs, like `myapp` and `myapp.author`.  Then you can include the author CSS (that has more specific selectors) only in edit mode.

Comment: I'm Using CQ5 so the problem is when someone make a template fox example to edit an Input Field, so when I use the Admin interface around the template, I see the input field of the UI like the template :( So That's the problem